# Weblogic 12c deployment null pointer exception

Tags: weblogic12c

encounter null pointer exception but I cannot find any hints in log:

`EJB deployment state REMOVED for [pas-app-master-app-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT-1:pas-app-master-app-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT-1, pas-app-master-ejb-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:pas-app-master-ejb-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT:pas-app-master-ejb-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar](PASServiceFacade, SampleSessionBean)`

`Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "680923808590731" for task "116" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.NullPointerException" weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.NullPointerException at weblogic.application.internal.flow.EnvContextFlow.activate(EnvContextFlow.java:81) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.colocated(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:508) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.getWsdlURL(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:338) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.createService(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:262) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.createTargetRef(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:130) at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.bindServiceRef(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:420) at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceRef(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1179) at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1146) at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1518) at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindEnvEntriesFromDDs(EnvironmentBuilder.java:2118) at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindEnvEntriesFromDDs(EnvironmentBuilder.java:2089) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.EnvContextFlow.activate(EnvContextFlow.java:79) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)`

Comment: The weblogic server's log should give more details about the deployment error, can you post it ?

Comment: This's all the log I can get